# Wildfly maven plugin not register web context

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, wildfly

When i using *wildfly maven plugin* for deploy my java ee application to my wildfly 8.1.0 standalone web application server with this POM configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
        <port>9991</port>
        <username>root</username>
        <password>manager</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If i run *mvn wildfly:deploy* the application is deployed and i've this message from server log console:

```
....
21:45:42,100 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "MyApp-0.0.1.war" (runtime-name: "MyApp-0.0.1.war")
21:45:42,819 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /MyApp-0.0.1
21:45:44,319 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS018562: Redeployed "MyApp-0.0.1.war"
....
```

If i specify the *name* parameter in *configuration* section of plugin into POM like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
        <port>9991</port>
        <username>root</username>
        <password>manager</password>
        <name>WebApp</name>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

the application is deployed but Web Context is not specified and if i go to: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/WebApp` the server show error page 404! When application is deployed with this parameter the server console log show only this message:

```
....
21:44:28,299 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS014900: Content added at location D:\Wildfly\standalone\data\content\c0\e78f2599016bf33187b1049001b210040b829a\content
21:44:28,299 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "WebApp" (runtime-name: "WebApp")
21:44:28,705 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS018559: Redeployed "WebApp" (runtime-name : "WebApp")
....
```

Why, only with name specification, the web context is not registerd? Can i specify the web context in configurations parameters like the application name? Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried this out and it turned out that you will have to set  to WebApp.war to get it working.

I would personally prefer setting the name directly in the  section using the  tag since this is more common and there you can omit the file extension.

Comment: Thanks so much @shi! After i've add _.war_ extension into <name>..</name> tag my problem was solved! About your suggestion... what is the section that you referring to? Not <configuration>...</configuration> of the plugin?

Comment: Sorry it did not write the tag names as it might have tried to interpret it as HTML, ... So add the finalName tag directly under the build tag in order to produce an artifact with the intended name.